# Define Gurobi variable based on other variable

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I'm using Gurobi 9.0.0 with the Python API to solve an MIP. I'm stuck at expressing a variable that is defined based on another variable.

Specifically, I have a variable `x[i]` defined for a range of `i`. Now I want to create a variable `y[i]` which is the absolute difference between `x[i]` and `x[i+1]` for the defined range of `i`. The end goal is to minimize the maximum of `y` over all `i` in the objective.

I tried defining the variable as follows:

```
y[i] = model.addVar(abs_(x[i] - x[i+1]) for i in range(i_range - 1))
```

but Gurobi throws an error

```
File "model.pxi", line 2562, in gurobipy.Model.addVar
TypeError: must be real number, not GenExpr
```

Directly defining the objective based on `x`, without `y`, also gives me errors.

This must be a quite typical use case. How do I define it properly in Gurobi?

Comment: (Not having access to gurobi) imho this looks very far away from valid code and you should be a bit more cautious about python-syntax, dimensionality and function-signatures. The `for range` part looks not like valid python to me. Even if it would be a list comprehension, the dimensions would not be valid as your left-hand-side is already indexed while the right would be something iterable. Futhermore, `abs_()` according to the docs, asks for a variable, not an expression. It also generates an temporary object to be used with constraints not variables. Define `y` and use `abs_` in constraints.

Comment: Yes @sascha you are right, I posted an answer pretty aligned with the points you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that at `AddVar(abs_(x[i] - x[i+1] for range(i_range - 1)` part you are trying to add a single variable with the command but a generator expression(i.e. multiple expressions indexed by `i`) as its argument. That causes the error you got.

A common step to add definitions like this is to add two variables, `y` as a real (free sign) variable and `z` nonnegative variable, both indexed by the same set as `x`, and then add the following constraints:

`model.addConstrs(y[i] == x[i] - x[i+1]) for i in range(i_range - 1))`

`m.addConstr(z == abs_(y))`

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that myself: 1. Define proper variable; 2. "Assign" variable value use a constraint. Makes sense now. Sorry for all the typos; they're fixed now and were not the main issue.

Comment: @sascha thanks for the feedback, I corrected the answer considering your comments. CGFoX, can you check the new version and let us know if the new code for the model is working as expected?